# What AdaptiveCards' AdaptiveSpacing.Padding supposed to do?

Tags: adaptive-cards

I want to add padding to an **AdaptiveContainer** and tried to use `Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.Padding` but this seems to have no effect. Does anyone know what this flag supposed to do?

Comment: Hey,it would be great to get a litle bit more context. Can you give us some card example where you're trying to add this? Best suggestion is to try things in the designer and see how they behave there aswell.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with providing an example code. Or you know what this flag does or you don't.

Comment: If or if not the setting has an effect depends on where its actually used in the card. So its related to what your card looks like in general ie means to answer your question your card template is required......